# how to style image tag by src?

Tags: css, html

I have a image tag like,

```
<img src="image/path/goes/here/random_id">
```

and the random_id is changing randomly. How to catch this tag from an external css file without using id,class or any other attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path contains selector on src attribute
acording to this

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

```css
img[src*="image/path/goes/here/"]{
  border:1px solid red;
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="image/path/goes/here/123">
<img src="image/path/goes/here/321">

<img src="this/is/another/path/321">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are aiming to . However this is the solution you asked for (I suggest to give a style using jQuery selector as it seems you are using dynamic IDs .

```css
img[src="hello/world/123"]{
  border:10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="hello/world/123">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a div tag and the reference it as a child.

```
<div>
  <img src="your_path/path">
</div>
```

Then in CSS..

```
div:first-child {
do css here...
}
```